# How to parse a date and time in the format 2012-12-12T00:00:00+00:00?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I have a CSV file with dates in the following format:

```
2012-06-20T00:00:00+00:00
```

Is it possible to parse a date or date and time in this format? The goal is to turn it into a date and time that Google Spreadsheet understands.

The format is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.

Comment: The quoted date notation has this format: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD`, yet your last example has `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss`. Which should we use?

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss`. I don't care about the time zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
=left(A1,10)+mid(A1,12,8)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.